# Why is 9a4117b lost after f6a0890 is submitted

Tags: git, github

github:
Why is 9a4117b lost after f6a0890 is submitted

```
* |   commit 5d....
|\ \  Merge: f6a0890 9a4117b
| | | Author: j
| | | Date:   Tue Oct 5 18:36:36 2021 +0900
| | |
| | |     Merge branch 'test' of https://github.com/... into test
| | |
| * |   commit 9a4117b
| |\ \  Merge: be7c0a9 96b11a7
| | | | Author: s
| | | | Date:   Tue Oct 5 17:28:55 2021 +0900
| | | |
| | | |     Merge branch 'dev' into test
| | | |
* | | |   commit f6a0890
|\ \ \ \  Merge: be7c0a9 110853f
| |/ / /  Author: j
|/| | /   Date:   Tue Oct 5 18:35:51 2021 +0900
| | |/
| |/|         merge commit 2
| | |
| * | commit 110853f
| |/  Author: j
| |   Date:   Tue Oct 5 18:33:55 2021 +0900
| |
| |       commit 2
| |
| * commit 96b11a7
| | Author: s
| | Date:   Tue Oct 5 13:16:25 2021 +0900
| |
| |     commit 1
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. To get an answer to your question, you will have to explain a bit more your issue, and your question. Something along the lines : "I did this and that ... I expected to see ... Instead, I see ..."

Comment: If by "submit" you mean "push", then it is because `9a4117b` is not an ancestor of `f6a0890` as you can clearly see in the chart.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.